# How do I check the dragdrop.html?

Tags: mithril.js

I want to check the link destination code.

https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/next/dragdrop.html

Anyway, it was changed as follows, is it necessary to write something on the server side (PHP)?

```
//url: "http://localhost/api/files",
url: "http://myfakesite.com/api/files/post/",
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to test mithril. Put the `url` to a http://requestb.in/

You should be able to see the file contents there